# How to check if a node in Maya is read only using Python

Tags: python, maya

I was trying to find a Maya command or flag to use to check if a node is read only in Maya using Python. There does not seem to be a direct way to query this, but it must be needed fairly often?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the command `lockNode()` will help.

Answer (score 0):

The following command with `readOnly (ro)` flag lists all DAG nodes that are read-only.

```
cmds.ls(dag=True, ro=True)
```

If you want to check a specific node, use this command:

```
cmds.ls('character_USDZ', ro=True)
```